# Act As Paranoid: really destroy record that has paranoid children

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-paranoid

I'm using ActAsParanoid gem to soft delete some records, let's say the children. The parent is not paranoid, and I want that on destroy of the parent, the children get really destroyed.

```
class Parent < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :children, dependent: :destroy
end

class Child < ApplicationRecord
  act_as_paranoid 
  belongs_to :parent
end
```

I'm now seeing that the children are being soft deleted, preventing the parent to be destroyed because the reference in the child becomes invalid. How can I make the children be really destroyed after the parent gets destroyed? (I want to know if I can to avoid custom callbacks or not)

Update:

Using `dependent: :delete_all` gives the same error if there is one of the children that had been previously deleted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually your case is not being considered in `Paranoia` gem. If you see the documentation, there are [examples](https://github.com/rubysherpas/paranoia#destroying-through-association-callbacks) for other scenarios, but not the one you want.

`dependent` attribute in `has_many` association only accepts `destroy`, `delete_all`, `nullify`, `restrict_with_exception`, `restrict_with_error` as you can see [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#dependent). So you can't call `really_destroy!` there.

Luckily, there is a [`before_destroy`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Callbacks/before_destroy) callback that you can use to perform `really_destroy!` in each children. Try something like this:

```
class Parent < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :children

  before_destroy :really_destroy_children!

  private

  def really_destroy_children!
    children.with_deleted.each do |child|
      child.really_destroy!
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: That's what I was afraid. Thank you for confirming, pointing to the docs, and adding the code.

Comment: I edited it: Added an unscoped so it would also hard delete soft deleted children

Comment: @LeticiaEsperon Feel free to add a pull request in the gem repo in order to make the scenario available ;)

Comment: There is a typo, an extra dot after each but it doesn't let me edit it @DanielBatalla

Comment: Fixed! Thanks @LeticiaEsperon